# JQuery Slider not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I have a slider that is working fine in all browsers except Safari and I have been trying to get my head around this one. You can see the fiddler code here: http://jsfiddle.net/sjramsay/UyvvL/

It seems when the code gets to this point:

```
$("#slider-wrapper").animate({ marginLeft : newMargin }, SlideSpeed, function () { SetNavigationDisplay() });
```

The slider will not animate. I have checked all the values and everything looks to be pulling fine, but for some reason this just won't work in Safari. Anyone else run into this issue?

When I try this person's like: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-relative-move-div-left-right/ it seems to work when I try it in Safari so I am not entirely sure what I am missing.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Works for me safari win7:  http://jsfiddle.net/UyvvL/1/

Comment: I can't get it to work on WinXP Safari 5.1.7 Edit: I also navigate to our site through my cell phone on the iPhone's safari and it does not slide there either.

Comment: I took the code behind from jsFiddler and put that into a test page and I am able to get that to work, but when I put it in my website it doesn't work again. I am guessing there is a conflict somewhere. Is there an easy way to figure out where the conflict is?

Answer (score 0):

Update. After hours of trying to figure this out line by line, it was the  that everything was encapsulated in. This  had an attribute of align="center" for some reason, Safari does not like this. Once I remove it, everything works perfectly